# MIPS multiplication problem

Tags: mips

In MIPS, how can I tranlate this expression to MIPS?

`y = 2x+3z` (x,y,z are variables)

I use `multi $t0,$s0, 2 # $s0 stores x and $s1 stores y.` to show `2x`. Is that correct?

Comment: Can't you just try it in your simulator (SPIM I expect ?) ? BTW, you forgot the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

x is in $s0
z is in $s1
y will be in $s2

```
add $s2, $s0, $s0    # x*2 in $s2
add $t0, $s1, $s1    # z*2 in $t0
add $t0, $t0, $s1    # z*3 in $t0
add $s2, $s2, $t0    # x*2+z*3 in $s2
```

We don't actually multiply (it's slower than simple addition) and as you can see we destroy temporary register $t0 but don't touch $s0/$s1